# Applicability of DCT, MCT, Fatou's lemma to a sequence of random variables indexed by real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

The statements for DCT, MCT and Fatou's lemma are written for a sequence of random variables, $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$.

My question is that the above results can be still applied to a stochstic process $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ indexed by real number.

Comment: Yes because if $E(X_t)$ doesn't converge to $E(X)$ then there is a sequence $t_n\to\infty$ such that $E(X_{t_n})$ doesn't converge to $E(X)$, and this contradicts DCT/MCT. Using MCT you get Fatou.